# Avoid both static & dynamic casting

Tags: c++, oop, downcast

I'm updating a system that receives multicast messages, parses the data into classes, then passes
a base class pointer to a separate thread through a queue.  The other thread then reads the data
from the classes, and stores them in tables.

There are 2 different kinds of messages we receive.  Here's the class design:

```
class BaseMsg
{
public:
    BaseMsg(char tp) : msgType(tp) {}
    virtual ~BaseMsg() = 0;

    char msgType;
}

class MsgType1 : public BaseMsg
{
public:
    MsgType1( int a, int b) : BaseMsg('1'), val1(a), val2(b) {}
    virtual ~MsgType1();

    int val1, val2;
}

class MsgType2 : public BaseMsg
{
public:
    MsgType2( double a, double b) : BaseMsg('2'), val1(a), val2(b) {}
    virtual ~MsgType2();

    double val1, val2;
}
```

Here's the receive code:

```
void reciveMessage( char *datablob, MsgQueue *queue)
{
    BaseMsg *msgReceived;
    char type = datablob[0];    // message type is the first character in the data,
                                // the rest of the blob varies based on that type
    if ( type == '1' ) {
        // code for parsing type 1 into 2 ints, i1, i2
        msgReceived = new MsgType1( i1, i2);
    } else {
        // code for parsing type 2 into 2 doubles, d1, d2
        msgReceived = new MsgType2( d1, d2);
    }
    queue->push(msgReceived);
}
```

Here's the process code which runs in a separate thread:

```
void processMessage(MsgQueue *queue)
{
    BaseMsg *msgToProcess = queue->pop();

    if ( msgToProcess->msgType == '1' ) {
        MsgType1 *mt1 = static_cast<MsgType1 *>(msgToProcess);
        // do stuff with the message type 1 data
    } else {
        MsgType2 *mt2 = static_cast<MsgType2 *>(msgToProcess);
        // do stuff with the message type 2 data
    }
}
```

I know that the check for message type then downcasting is sloppy, but given the contraints of communicating
through the queue, I could not come up with a better solution.  Even using dynamic_cast<> (which
I don't want to do for performance reasons) would entail the same issue; it still needs to know
what type of class to convert msgToProcess into.

Any suggestions about how I could get rid of the checks & casting?  I have a lot of experience
with C & C++, but not much with OO design, so there may be a way I know nothing about.

Also note that this is an extremely stripped-down example to illustrate the question.  There
are actually over 50 different message types, and performance is critical, as we can receive
millions of messages per second.

Comment: In the "do stuff" section, is there a way you can implement it in terms of virtual function calls in the base class?

Comment: You can minimize the number of places `downcast` is used but you cannot avoid it. See [my answer to another SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43038856/434551) for ideas on how to make it less repetitive.

Comment: If you don't want to rely on RTTI (casting), you might want to use a discriminating union, but you would still need a switch statement over an enum, there is also std::variant that does a similar job. I haven't tried performance, but I suppose it will be really fast because you don't need to store any kind of indirection so you will benefit from cache locality.

Comment: In reply to RyanP: That would be extremely messy.  There are over 50 message types, the data in each is fairly different. Just in that example, I would need 4 functions to get the different val contents.  In the real system, there would be hundreds of those virtual functions.

Comment: Worrying about the speed of a `dynamic_cast` is generally the wrong thing to do -- a `dynamic_cast` generally costs less than a branch mispredict, so if you're worried about things at that level, think about branch predictability.  But this definitely seems like premature optimization.

Comment: In response to Chris: I have control of the classes, so there isn't a chance for a miscast.  I'm trying to find an OO solution to eliminate the casts, not replace the static with a dynamic cast.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with others who have suggested to use the inherent properties of polymorphism and use member functions.

But I also understand the need to keep the message classes pretty clean. I think using a Visitor Pattern (that relies on polymorphism) may be a good idea in this case:

```
class BaseMsg {
public:
    virtual void accept(MsgProcessor& p) = 0;
};

class Msg1 : BaseMsg {
public:
    void accept(MsgProcessor& p) { p.process(*this); }
};

class Msg2 : BaseMsg {
public:
    void accept(MsgProcessor& p) { p.process(*this); }
};

class MsgProcessor {
public:
    void process(Msg1& m);
    void process(Msg2& m);
}
```

The cool thing is that this will not compile if one of the functions is missing for *any* of the derived classes.

edit: Fixed stuff pointed out in comments

edit2: with two codebases & minimal changes in the external codebase:

External codebase:

```
class MsgVisitor;
class BaseMsg {
public:
    virtual void accept(MsgVisitor&) = 0;
};

class Msg1;
class Msg2;
class MsgVisitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(Msg1&) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Msg2&) = 0;
};

class Msg1 : public BaseMsg {
public:
    void accept(MsgVisitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
};

class Msg2 : public BaseMsg {
public:
    void accept(MsgVisitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
};
```

Local codebase:

```
class MsgProcessor : public MsgVisitor {
public:
    void visit(Msg1& m) { ... } // do stuff for Msg1
    void visit(Msg2& m) { ... }
};

void processMessage(MsgQueue *queue)
{
    BaseMsg *msgToProcess = queue->pop();
    msgToProcess->accept(MsgProcessor());
    //delete msgToProcess;
}
```

Comment: Doing this, or the suggestions above, would involve a massive rewrite of the classes/structures used in the "do stuff" area, which are not in any logical hierarchy.  Unfortunately, that's all legacy code which is over a dozen years old, and maintained by another group.  I was tasked with reworking the incoming data, and tying that to the legacy code.  While I would love to rewrite that code, that's not an option right now. :-(

Comment: @DanielJour your comment does not even attempt to answer the question, just nit-pick non-relevant items in a massively stripped down example.

Comment: @FlyboyWilson which is why it was a comment and not an answer ;) (providing feedback and critique is one of the intended uses of comments on this site)

Comment: @FlyboyWilson Does that mean you have to work with the `processMessage` function and cannot change any interface?

Comment: @FlyboyWilson What do you mean? It seem like you could just copy-paste every block of "do stuff" code into the corresponding `MsgProcessor::process` function. And `MsgProcessor` can have members if it needs external context.

Comment: @Shadow Pretty much yes.  If I had more time, maybe I could restructure it to implement the suggestions above, but I don't have the time, and I can't justify it (to myself or management) just to avoid the casts.

Comment: @FlyboyWilson I have updated my reply to your split-code context

Comment: @FlyboyWilson The justification to management is not "I want to avoid casts". The justification is "I want to refactor this code to reduce the costs of future maintenance and to reduce the likelyhood of serious bugs".

Comment: @harmic That would work great if I want my bosses to go out like the weasels in "Who Framed Roger Rabbit" :-).  I've been working in this industry for 25+ years, and I've yet to meet management that wants to spend time/money *now* to reduce costs at some later time, when they will no longer be here.  Unfortunately, that's how much of the industry operates, and so C++ often gets used as a glorified C.  I know that some companies are more progressive, and think in the longer term, but I have not had the fortune to work at any of them.

Answer (score 2):

I would define a pure-virtual function called for example, `doStuff()` within the class `BaseMsg`.
Each derived class implements that method.
Within your `processMessage`, you simply call `msgToProcess->doStuff()`

Comment: I considered that solution, but that would mean that the classes that now just contain messages would need to know about all the work that goes on in the "do stuff" sections, which is a mess of data manipulation. and repackaging. The goal was to minimally tie the 2 parts together, and just have the "do stuff" code know about both sets of structures.

Comment: doStuff(BaseProcessor *) may provide better scalability : )

Comment: This. "I know that the check for message type then downcasting is sloppy, but..." You should just rely on polymorphism, that's what it's there for.